# TF900558: This build process template cannot be run on build server -Controller. Upgrade this build server to a newer version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

I'm New In VS and TFS

Form my Build definition We are using custom Build Process template for ant script VS2012. Requirement is to move from ant script to MSBuild

I created Build Definition in Visual Studio  2012, and using default Build process Template but was getting some errors in Build Process Template, after research i figured out that I need to Update my Visual Studio to latest one.

No i have VS 2015. I included .proj file and added MSBuild Arguments and when I'm trying to Queue Build Definition getting this error "TF900558: This build process template cannot be run on build server -Controller. Upgrade this build server to a newer version."

Some advice please, what is wrong ?

Comment: What build process template are you using? The message indicates that you're using a build process template designed for a newer version of TFS.

Comment: I'm using default build process template of VS2015 
Default Template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml)
Build Definition was created in VS 2012

Comment: The default template for TFS 2012 is `DefaultTemplate.11.xaml`. `TfvcTemplate.12` is the TFS 2013 default build process template. If you're using a TFS 2012 build controller, `TfvcTemplate.12` won't work. The build process template has nothing to do with the version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 14.0.24712.0 and it uses TfvcTemplate.12.xaml. On My Build Server I have Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010. what is the best option to fix this issue? updating tfs on Build Server? 
what if I would not like to update tfs on Build server ? what can you advice in this case ? 

Best Regards, Gari

Comment: Use `DefaultTemplate.xaml`, or upgrade your build server, or better yet start using the new build system that was introduced in TFS 2015.

Comment: We can't update Build Server now, I decide to create custom Build process Template in tfs 2015 which will work for tfs 2010 build controller, is it correct idea ?